# After Importing the "Browser animation module in **Module.ts** file ( by running **npm install** @angular/animations)

Tags: angular8, angular-animations

After Importing the "BrowserAnimationModule in **Module.ts** file ( by running `npm install` @angular/animations)

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ...,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

***still its shows***

> **Error : Found the synthetic property @animate. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your
>   application**

***On inspect->console***

```
ERROR Error: Found the synthetic property @animate. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
    at checkNoSyntheticProp (platform-browser.js:2088)
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.setProperty (platform-browser.js:2052)
    at BaseAnimationRenderer.setProperty (animations.js:501)
    at DebugRenderer2.setProperty (core.js:40022)
    at setElementProperty (core.js:37214)
    at checkAndUpdateElementValue (core.js:37124)
    at checkAndUpdateElementInline (core.js:37052)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:38468)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:38411)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:39433)
```

Answer (score 1):

The **BrowserAnimationsModule** must be imported in the main module of the application **app.module.ts** and after importing, it is necessary to restart the application so that the imported module is recognized.